# How to get complete href links using beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, request

I am trying to get top movies name by genre. I couldn't get complete href links for that, I stuck by getting half href links

By the following code I got,

```
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=action&sort=user_rating,desc&title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=adventure&sort=user_rating,desc&title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=animation&sort=user_rating,desc&title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,
https://www.imdb.com/search/title?genres=biography&sort=user_rating,desc&title_type=feature&num_votes=25000,
.........
```

Like that but i want to all top 100 movies name by its genre like action, Adventure, Animation, Biography.......

I tried the following code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://www.imdb.com'
main_url = url + '/chart/top'
res = requests.get(main_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
for href in soup.find_all(class_='subnav_item_main'):
               # print(href)
               all_links = url + href.find('a').get('href')
               print(all_links)
```

I want complete link as shown bellow from [a link](https://www.imdb.com/chart/top)

```
/search/title?genres=action&amp;sort=user_rating,desc&amp;title_type=feature&amp;num_votes=25000,&amp;pf_rd_m=A2FGELUUNOQJNL&amp;pf_rd_p=5aab685f-35eb-40f3-95f7-c53f09d542c3&amp;pf_rd_r=FM1ZEBQ7E9KGQSDD441H&amp;pf_rd_s=right-6&amp;pf_rd_t=15506&amp;pf_rd_i=top&amp;ref_=chttp_gnr_1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need another loop over those urls and a limit to only get 100. I store in a dictionary with keys being genre and values being a list of films. Note original titles may appear e.g. The Mountain II (2016) is Dag II (original title).

`links` is a list of tuples where I keep the genre as first item and url as second.

```
import requests, pprint
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from urllib.parse import  urljoin

url = 'https://www.imdb.com/chart/top'    
genres = {}

with requests.Session() as s:
    r = s.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    links = [(i.text, urljoin(url,i['href'])) for i in soup.select('.subnav_item_main a')]

    for link in links:
        r = s.get(link[1])
        soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
        genres[link[0].strip()] = [i['alt'] for i in soup.select('.loadlate', limit = 100)]

pprint.pprint(genres)
```

---

**Sample output:**

[image]

Comment: Hello Sir, I am trying to save this output into csv file but its not. is there any special syntax's to do it

Comment: try :    df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(genres,orient='index').transpose()   then df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv', sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )

Comment: Sir, i am not using pandas in that, is there any way to without pandas like simple python syntax

Comment: don't create a dictionary of lists then. Instead have  insert  genre at position 0 of the  list generated by list comprehension e.g. row = [i['alt'] for i in soup.select('.loadlate', limit = 100)]  then row.insert(0, genres[link[0].strip())   then csv.writerow(row)